# Deleting Files That are X days old without forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently trying to write a windows batch script that will work on Win XP and 7. I need to delete files in a certain directory if they are more than 10 days old. This is not a tool just for myself but for many, so I can never say for sure if someone has the forfiles.exe on their computer. Is there a way to delete files in a given directory if they are a certain number of days old without using forfiles?

Thank you very much I appreciate it!

Comment: WMIC can help if you use XP Pro and up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `dir /T:W *.*` to get the date-modified from all files in a directory. Add some conditional testing and then delete files that match your criteria.